# mysql--- select result that some key is null in join table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table in mysql

```
user_titem
item_id     item_name
------------------------
  1            a 
  2            b
  3            c
  5            d

track
--------------------------------------------------------
track_no      member_ID       member_track   track_type
   1              2                1            titem
   2              2                2            titem
   3              2                3            titem
   5              2                13           titem
   6              2                5            titem
```

In track, member_track will refer to item_id, so if i do this select statement:

```
SELECT track.track_no ,track.track_type, user_titem.item_name ,user_titem.item_id 
FROM track 
LEFT JOIN user_titem ON track.member_track=user_titem.item_id 
WHERE track.track_type = 'titem' and track.member_ID='2'
```

the result is

```
result
-----------------------------------
track_no    track_type    item_name   item_id
    5          titem         NULL       NULL
```

The item_name and item_id is null because in track_no(5), member_track(refer to item_id) is not in user_titem.

Now the problem is, how can i just get the track_no directly in one select statement when the member_track of track_no is null.

The result that i want

```
result
-----------
track_no   
    5
```

How can i solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add additional check in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT track.track_no
FROM track
LEFT JOIN user_titem ON track.member_track=user_titem.item_id 
WHERE track.track_type = 'titem' and track.member_ID='2' 
AND user_titem.item_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try

```
SELECT track_no FROM track where member_track NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM user_titem)
```

I think it will give the same result.